# What's wrong with my std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping call?

Tags: rust

I've got a problem with my function `save_vec` that saves a vector down to disk using mmap. It creates the file with the right size but when I check its contents (using `hexdump`) it's just all zeros. The `mmap` is using `MAP_SHARED` and not private so assuming there's something wrong with my `copy_nonoverlapping` call.

```
fn save_vec<T: Encodable + Debug + Copy>(path: &str, v: &Vec<T>) -> Option<String> {
    println!("save_vec");
    let mut encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::encode(v, SizeLimit::Infinite).unwrap();
    let len = encoded.len();
    println!("encoded = {:?}", encoded);
    println!("len = {:?}", len);
    let file = match OpenOptions::new()
            .create(true)
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .open(path) {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(err) => return Some("cannot create file".to_string())
    };
    file.set_len(len as u64);

    let fd = file.as_raw_fd();
    unsafe {
        let mmap_len = len as libc::size_t;
        let prot = libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_WRITE;
        let flags = libc::MAP_SHARED;
        let ptr = libc::mmap(0 as *mut libc::types::common::c95::c_void, mmap_len, prot, flags, fd, 0);
        if ptr == libc::MAP_FAILED {
            return Some("mmap fail".to_string())
        }
        let byte_ptr: *const u8 = mem::transmute(ptr);
        let encoded_ptr: *mut u8 = encoded.as_mut_ptr();
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(byte_ptr, encoded_ptr, len);
        libc::munmap(ptr, len as u64);
        println!("byte_ptr={:?}", byte_ptr);
    }

    None
}
```

Comment: Maybe related to this? http://internals.rust-lang.org/t/memcpy-is-backwards/1797

Comment: You really should attempt to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting code that uses (but does not require) an external library, leaving out required `use` statements, these all make it harder for us to help you.

Comment: And this suffices a downvote?

Comment: @jimjampez I think so. Other people may not - they can also upvote it. The downvote link says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* I feel that a MCVE contributes to "research effort" as it is work done by the poster to understand the problem. However, if you make it into an MCVE, I tend to remove my downvotes (just make sure to ping me to look again!) ^_^

Comment: I just won't put my Rust questions on SO anymore as your draconian down-votes puts me off.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably being bitten by the [last-minute change to the argument order of ptr::copy and friends](http://users.rust-lang.org/t/psa-late-silent-breakage-for-beta/816). Specifically, this part of your code:

```
let byte_ptr: *const u8 = mem::transmute(ptr); // Why is this const?
let encoded_ptr: *mut u8 = encoded.as_mut_ptr(); // Why is this mutable?
ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(byte_ptr, encoded_ptr, len);
```

The compiler actually gave you some indication that something was wrong, in that you "needed" a *mutable* pointer to the source of data. That doesn't make any sense - we are just reading from that slice. And the destination was constant, which means we **can't change it**.

Here's the full code I ran that worked:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::{mem,ptr};
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;

fn save_vec(path: &str, v: &[u8]) -> Result<(), String> {
    let len = v.len();

    let f =
        OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .open(path);

    let file = try!(f.map_err(|_| "cannot create file".to_string()));
    file.set_len(len as u64).unwrap();

    let fd = file.as_raw_fd();
    unsafe {
        let mmap_len = len as libc::size_t;
        let prot = libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_WRITE;
        let flags = libc::MAP_SHARED;
        let ptr = libc::mmap(0 as *mut libc::types::common::c95::c_void, mmap_len, prot, flags, fd, 0);
        if ptr == libc::MAP_FAILED {
            return Err("mmap fail".to_string())
        }
        let byte_ptr: *mut u8 = mem::transmute(ptr);
        let encoded_ptr: *const u8 = v.as_ptr();
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(encoded_ptr, byte_ptr, len);
        libc::munmap(ptr, len as u64);
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    save_vec("dump", b"hello").unwrap();
}
```